# Windows 10 BSOD PFN list corrupt

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I was playing a game on ma notebook with Windows 10 when after 5 - 10 minutes I got BSOD and the notebook turned off instead of restarting.

**This happened 3 times** and I was not able to turn it on for about 5 minutes after each BSOD, so my first thought was that it overheated.

After third BSOD I checked the error message and it was saying: **PFN LIST CORRUPT**

My notebook is ASUS G56JR with Kingstom SSDNOW V300 as System drive.

Comment: Did you find the cause of this BSOD? Also provide more details about this error, may be helpful to readers ^_^

Comment: Unfortunately I did not find the exact cause of this BSOD. More information can be found in the article I posted in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this article: https://www.reviversoft.com/blog/2013/09/pfn-list-corrupt/ I tried first and the most simple solution, running **chkdsk** as Administrator.

This seems to solve the problem since I did not get any more BSOD from then.

1. Click the Start button
2. Search for **chkdsk.exe** program
3. Right click on it and choose **Run as administrator**
4. Wait for program to complete(it closes itself after its finished)